# ShareCompat.IntentBuilder - How to remove own app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Good day

I am using ShareCompat.IntentBuilder to share images to other apps. It is working as expected but in the share menu that pops up my own app is shown as well.

Is there a way to remove or blacklist my own app? Thanks in advance

Below is the code I am using to share jpeg images:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    activity,
    FileProviderUtil.AUTHORITY,
    imageFile);

Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setStream(uri)
    .setSubject(activity.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setText(activity.getString(R.string.share_content_message, ""))
    .setChooserTitle(R.string.share)
    .setType("image/jpeg")
    .getIntent();

intent.setData(uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```